# Comparing Grammar of Two Forms of A Quote

Tags: grammaticality, quotes

First of all, I am not a native English speaker, so sorry if this question seems very basic for some of you.

Among the following two quotes, which grammar would make more sense, and why:

1- original:

"Respect the old when you are young. Help the weak when you are strong. confess the fault when you are Wrong. Because one day in life you will be old, weak and ***wrong***."

2- my correction:

"Respect the old when you are young. Help the weak when you are strong. confess the Fault when you are Wrong. Because one day in life you will be old, weak and ***wronged***."

The quote has three main parts:

1- Respect the old when you are young because one day in life you will be old *(so you want others to respect you)*

2- Help the weak when you are strong because onde day in life you will be weak. *(so you want others to help you)*

**3- Confess the fault when you are wrong because one day in life you will be (wrong/wronged).** *(so you want others to confess their fault)*

For some reason, I feel using 'wronged' instead of 'wrong' makes more sense?

Comment: The first: consistency.

Comment: I find it a little odd that there is a lack of consistency with capitalization in both versions. Why isn't it *Old*, *Young*, and *Weak* (in capitals) in the first two sentences—just as it's both *Fault* and *Wrong* in the third sentence? Or why is any of it capitalized? It would be more consistent to capitalize all of those words, or capitalize none of them.

Comment: To be wrong and to be wronged are not the same.

Comment: Your "correction" has changed the meaning, not because of grammar but because *wronged* does not mean the same thing as *wrong*.

Comment: Thanks all! I know that wrong and wronged are different things. WRONG = to wrong someone or be incorrect.  where WRONGED = someone has done you wrong.   The quote has three main parts: 1- Respect the old when you are young because one day in life you will be old 2- help the weak when you are strong because onde day in life you will be weak. 3- confess the fault when you are wrong because one day in life you will be (wrong/wronged). For some reason, I feel using wronged make more sense?

Comment: You are correct that "logically" using "wronged" would seem more appropriate.  But the quote is essentially poetic, and the choice of terms/meanings is up to the writer.

Comment: You won't be young anymore. You won't be strong anymore. But you will still be wrong, at least some of the time.

Comment: Peter , it is possible to be strong at least some of the time (exactly like wrong some of the time.) Strength is a variable throughout most peoples lives, sometimes it is up and sometimes it is down. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with the ‘improvement’.  Strong and weak are opposites, tortfeasor and victim are reciprocals; the analogy breaks down if *wrong* is on both sides.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes.  In effect, it is a matter not of grammar but of rhetorical consistency.  It is also factually inaccurate. At me advanced age I can tell you from experience that I am old but never wrong.

Comment: Thanks Tuffy, I think being right or wrong is a relative thing (not an absolute matter.) Even if your statement is accurate where you say you are never wrong, some people would think that you have done something wrong by stating that out loud! This comment not meant to be taken seriously :) entertaining a thought!

Comment: As a non-native speaker, you should be aware of the existence of our sister site [ell.se], which I believe is far more appropriate for this sort of question.

Answer (score 2):

Your question comes down to the difference between two statements (advice).

1. Confess the fault when you are wrong because one day in life you will be wrong.
2. Confess the fault when you are wronged, because one day in life you will be wronged.

In statement #1, the main clause asks that you admit to being wrong, but then posits a future in which you will be wrong. But in both cases you are wrong, so where is the ethical wisdom?

In statement #2, you are asked to lie about being wronged, because in the future you will be wronged again. The logic escapes me.

Now, Confess the fault when you are wrong because one day you will be wronged (someone will resist admitting they are wrong in actions toward you) makes more ethical sense because your admission models the universal expectation, act as all should act: Kant.

Comment: Thanks @Zan700 for sharing your thought, so do you think using the word 'wronged' instead of 'wrong'  is a better choice?